# What's the deal with [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]?

Tags: iphone, variables, delegates

I am using [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] to share a variable across several classes. I set the value in the AppDelegate. I am able to NSLog it from the myAppDelegate.m and see the value. Then I try to NSLog the value when one of my Tabs loads, and it crashes:

```
myAppDelegate *app = (myAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSLog(@"Value:%@ ", app.delegateVar); // <--- Causes Crash
```

Basically seems like it is creating a new instance of app.delegateVar ?

delegateVar is defined in myAppDelegate.h and then it myAppDelegate.m I do this:

```
  - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

        ...

        [delegateVar release];
        delegateVar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test Value"];
        NSLog(@"%@",delegateVar);

    ...
    }
```

Comment: What the `delegateVar` property and how is it defined?

Comment: What is the name of your app delegate class? Normal naming conventions would be to have `AppDelegate.m` contain a class named `AppDelegate`, not `myAppDelegate`. (and class names are capitalized by convention, so "`myAppDelegate *app = ...`" looks suspicious.

Comment: The naming inconsistency was just an error in my editing when I posted here.

Comment: delegateVar is an NSMutableArray. I define it in myAppDelegate.m... see my edits above.

Comment: "Causes Crash" how? What error exactly are you getting?

Comment: Are you sure delegateVar is a `NSMutableArray`? It's being set to a string in your `applicationDidFinishLaunching`.

Comment: It just dies, like when you NSLog a bad variable. If I comment out the NSLog, it works - but of course there is no access to the delegateVar.

Comment: Sorry. NSMutableString. I'm messing up info, overtired.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility is that `delegateVar` is being released prematurely.

For example, maybe the delegateVar property is not set up with the `retain` option, you are explicitly calling `[delegateVar release]`, or you are bypassing the setter (and its retain semantics) by assigning directly to it (`delegateVar =` instead of `self.delegateVar =`).

In any case, look at the code that creates, assigns, and releases delegateVar.

---

Update:

Bingo.
This is your problem right here:

```
    [delegateVar release];
    delegateVar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test Value"];
    NSLog(@"%@",delegateVar);
```

You are assigning an autoreleased value (from +NSString stringWithFormat:) to delegateVar, and are not doing anything to retain it. That means that as soon as `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` returns, delegateVar is automatically released (and becomes invalid).

If delegateVar is a property with the "retain" option defined, you should be doing this as:

```
self.delegateVar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test Value"];
```

You don't need to release delegateVar before assigning to it (using self.delegateVar =), because the setter will release the old value as needed. But you *do* need to release it in your `dealloc` method.

Comment: Ahhh yes, the ol' "premature release" problem.

Comment: Premature releasing is a serious problem. I have friends that suffer from premature releasing and simply raising awareness of the condition helps other premature releasers to confront their problem and find ways to deal with it.

Comment: Yes looks like it was a premature release problem. And to think that my girlfriend never complained...

Answer (score 2):

David Gelhar has likely found the cause of the issue, however when you have memory management issues (`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is a sign of memory management problems), there are a number of things you can do:

1. Re-read the Cocoa [memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) and make sure that you're following them.
2. Run the [static analyser](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/StaticAnalysis/). This will often pick up places where you have neglected the memory management rules.
3. Try using [`NSZombieEnabled`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/130-Debugging_Applications/debugging_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH7-SW3) to find out whether you are sending messages to unallocated instances.